# GCC Optimization Option

Tags: gcc

Recently, I used GCC to compile a program, but when I used `-O1` optimization option, it went wrong; there was no problem when using `-O0`. So I replaced the `-O1` with those options as the official documentation said, such as `-fauto-inc-dec`, `-fcompare-elim`, `-fcprop-registers`, etc.
However, it works fine without any bug but the performance is not very good.

I want to know whether `-O1` is equivalent to those little compilation options?

Comment: It sounds like your program actually has a bug, probably caused by undefined behaviour, that accidentally works with -O0. You should fix the bug.

Comment: Thank you,sir. That is very possible. Howerver, I am interested in the difference from the -O1 and those optimization flags that -O1 turns on. Why do they have different effects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turning on optimization at all (`-O1` vs `-O0`) changes the code generation in ways that `-f` flags do not control.  Note this sentence in the [gcc documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html):

> Not all optimizations are controlled directly by a flag. Only optimizations that have a flag are listed in this section.

Some details depend on very specific gcc version numbers (e.g., gcc 4.2 vs gcc 4.5, 4.9, etc).

Answer (score 1):

[The `-O1` will turn on the following optimization flags:](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html)

```
      -fauto-inc-dec 
      -fcompare-elim 
      -fcprop-registers 
      -fdce 
      -fdefer-pop 
      -fdelayed-branch 
      -fdse 
      -fguess-branch-probability 
      -fif-conversion2 
      -fif-conversion 
      -fipa-pure-const 
      -fipa-profile 
      -fipa-reference 
      -fmerge-constants
      -fsplit-wide-types 
      -ftree-bit-ccp 
      -ftree-builtin-call-dce 
      -ftree-ccp 
      -ftree-ch 
      -ftree-copyrename 
      -ftree-dce 
      -ftree-dominator-opts 
      -ftree-dse 
      -ftree-forwprop 
      -ftree-fre 
      -ftree-phiprop 
      -ftree-slsr 
      -ftree-sra 
      -ftree-pta 
      -ftree-ter 
      -funit-at-a-time
```

Comment: I have used them to replace -O1 but the effect was not the same.Is the adding sequence also very important?

Comment: Yes, pass sequence does matter in general.

Comment: Thank you, I want to know where can I get the sequence? GCC manual sorted it alphabetically.

Comment: @user2655195 I am not aware of a flag which prints the pass order but I guess one can dig it out from the pass manager code. Take a look at http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Pass-manager.html